# Search string in Multidimensional Array $value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which includes all of my directories in my homedir. I am running a foreach loop where I need to output "`</ul>`" for my dropdown menu. I need output the closing tags at the end of the last subdirectory of the parent directory or where there are line breaks. (I grouped my array by spaces below.)

I have no idea how to logically approach this problem. I figure maybe a recursive function would help but I do not know where to begin.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => test_php [1] => test_php ) 

        [1] => Array ( [0] => bootstrap-336-dist [1] => bootstrap-3.3.6-dist ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => .css [1] => bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => .fonts [1] => bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/fonts ) 
        [4] => Array ( [0] => .js [1] => bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js ) 

        [5] => Array ( [0] => dynasty_loop [1] => dynasty_loop ) 
        [6] => Array ( [0] => .C1_00626E58960C [1] => dynasty_loop/C1_00626E58960C ) 
        [7] => Array ( [0] => ..snap [1] => dynasty_loop/C1_00626E58960C/snap ) 
        [8] => Array ( [0] => .C1_00626E5894EF [1] => dynasty_loop/C1_00626E5894EF ) 
        [9] => Array ( [0] => ..snap [1] => dynasty_loop/C1_00626E5894EF/snap ) 

        [10] => Array ( [0] => nvr_snapshots [1] => nvr_snapshots ) 
        [11] => Array ( [0] => .snap [1] => nvr_snapshots/snap ) 

        [12] => Array ( [0] => test_php2 [1] => test_php2 ) )
```

Comment: can you put here your code that you try?

Comment: `// my own function
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}`

This is what I have so far, but I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is my answer if anyone is looking for something similar. My foreach loop syntax is not closed off so beware of that.

```
foreach($_SESSION['menulite'] as $key => $url) {
        $url_raw = $url;
        $key_raw = $key;

        $url[0]=trim($url[0],'.');

        $nextmenuitem = $_SESSION['menulite'][$key + 1];


            //if (substr($nextmenuitem[0],0,1)=='.') {
                $padding_left='';
                $padding_left = (substr_count($nextmenuitem[0], '.', 0, strpos($nextmenuitem[0], trim($nextmenuitem[0], '.'))) -1);


                if ( strpos( $url_raw[0],'.' ) !== 0 && strpos( $nextmenuitem[0],'.' ) !== 0 ) {

                $div1 = "<li role=\"presentation\">" ;
                $div2 = "</li>";
                    }

                if ( strpos( $url_raw[0],'.' ) !== 0 && strpos( $nextmenuitem[0],'.' ) === 0 ) {
                $div1 = "<li role=\"presentation\" $class1> <a$dropdown> $url_raw[0] $caret </a> <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">" ;
                $div2 = null;
                }

                if ( strpos( $url_raw[0],'.' ) === 0 && strpos( $nextmenuitem[0],'.' ) === 0 ) { 
                $div1 = "<li>" ;
                $div2 = "</li>";

                }

                if ( strpos( $url_raw[0],'.' ) === 0 && strpos( $nextmenuitem[0],'.' ) !== 0 ) { 
                    $div1 = "<li>" ;
                    $div2 = "</li>";
                    //echo "</ul>";


                    }
```